# Retuning minimum value from table within range of two values

Tags: indexing, return, unique, vlookup

I have two values for minimum 1D and maximum 1.5D for hardware engagement. I also have table of hardware length and number.

See snapshot:
[image: Img]

I need a formula in which it will search for minimum hardware length and respective number which is available in table (in above problem two hardware’s are within range 0.250 and 0.313, I need minimum of two). Finally, display in output cell.

Answer (score 0):

This may well need some adjustment (for example what would be the result desired from `.3` and `.375`) but hopefully gives an indication. Assumes the columns of the main table are named `Size` and `HNum` and the inputs are in A1 and B1:

Hardware size:

```
=INDEX(Size,IF(MATCH(A1,Size,1)+1<MATCH(B1,Size,1),MATCH(A1,Size,1)+1,MATCH(A1,Size,1)))
```

Hardware number:

```
=INDEX(HNum,IF(MATCH(A1,Size,1)+1<MATCH(B1,Size,1),MATCH(A1,Size,1)+1,MATCH(A1,Size,1)))
```